# Sum of sales by customer from two monthly sales tables - efficient query

Tags: sql-server

looking for most efficient query to sum the cost by customer for both months - there are two tables, one for Jan and one for Feb.
Would I do an inner join or a proc sql?  Looking for help. Thanks!

[image: Here are the two tables and the end result I'm looking for]

Added an image above because columns didn't stay in order when i typed below.

desired result:

```
cust 1 total from both tables
cust 2 total from both tables
cust 3 total from both tables



mo  cust   $  item
jan cust1 10 shoe
jan cust1 20 coat
jan cust1 30 misc
jan cust2 11 shoe
jan cust2 22 top
jan cust3 30 jean


mo  cust   $ item
feb cust1 15 misc
feb cust1 20 misc
feb cust1 25 jean
feb cust2 35 jean
feb cust3 12 top
feb cust3 30 top
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, it would be good thing to have the create table and insert scripts for your question and along with the expected output.

Comment: Seriously you should normalize your tables. Consider combine `table` and `table2` or more as one single table. After that you can have a "`efficient`" query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can only be as efficient as your table deign. I assume "$" isn't the actual column name:

```
select
    cust, sum(dollars) as dollars
from (
    select cust, dollars from table1 
    UNION ALL
    select cust, dollars from table2
     ) d
group by
   cust
```

Comment: yes and thank you, sorry about the data, was just trying to think through the process